# C# clear XML innertext but not nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML that looks like below.  How can I clear all the text within the nodes without deleting any of the nodes?  I want to go from my starting XML to my ending XML.

My issue is that when I do the following it clears out the nodes as well and I end up with just node1 with no children nodes:

```
lst = doc.selectNodes("node1");
 foreach (XmlNode node in lst)
            {
                node.InnerText = "";
            }
```

Starting XML:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node4>99999</node4>
  </node2>
  <node3>abdg</node3>
</node1>
```

Desired ending XML:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node4></node4>
  </node2>
  <node3></node3>
</node1>
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_InnerText) is pretty clear that you'd get the result you are getting: _"Setting this property replaces all the child nodes with the parsed contents of the given string."_ So, the code you've tried hardly counts as any real effort. Please take some time to produce an actual [mcve] that shows some actual attempt to solve this problem, and explain what _specifically_ it is you are having trouble with.

Comment: What do you want to do with *mixed content* nodes like `<A>some<b> mixed </b>content</A>` ?  And what about attribute values?  Clear them or leave them?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Peter, by selecting "all" nodes and assigning values to it would replace all the child nodes as well.

Instead, You could query for all Leaf Nodes in the Xml and then set the value to string.Empty. For example,

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var leafNodes = xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(x=>!x.Elements().Any());

foreach(var leaf in leafNodes)
{
    leaf.SetValue(string.Empty);
}
```

Output

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    <node4></node4>
  </node2>
  <node3></node3>
</node1>
```